Load special php code only on plugin page
i write this code:
$hook = add_menu_page(
'T5 Demo',        // page title
'T5 Demo',        // menu title
'manage_options', // capability
't5-demo',        // menu slug
'my_render_page'  // callback function
);

how to load one php code only this above menu page slug?
thanks

Just add the function by that name:
function my_render_page() {
    echo '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
    echo '<p>This is a demo page for the T5 plugin.</p>';
}

